# Update Picklist Values Via Matadata Api

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, custom-controller

There are three Picklist values- Category, Product, And Version in such way Product depend on Category and Version depend on Product. I have requirement to edit the existing Picklist values while maintaining the dependencies that are already existing. I am using the metadata api and i am familiar with adding new values to the picklist, but not able to modify the existing values. Can anyone help with the above. Any responses are highly appreciated.